# Type-Length-Value vs. defined/structured Length-Value

Tags: protocols, data-representation, tlv

There's no doubt that a length-value representation of data is useful, but what advantages are there to type-length-value over it?

Of course, using LV requires the representation to be predefined or structured, but that's hardly ever a problem. Actually, I can't think of a good enough case where it wouldn't be defined enough that TLV would be required.

In my case, this is about data interchange/protocols. In every situation, the representation must be known to both parties to be processed, which eliminates the need for type explicitly inserted in the data. Any thoughts on when the type would be useful or necessary?

**Edit**
I should mention that a generic parser/processor would certainly benefit from the type information, but that's not my case.

Answer (score 1):

The only decent reason I could come up with is for a generic processor of the data, mainly for debugging or direct user presentation. Having the type embedded within the data would allow the processor to handle the data correctly without having to predefine all possible structures.

Answer (score 0):

The below point was mentioned in the wikipedia.

New message elements which are received at an older node can be safely skipped and the rest of the message can be parsed. This is similar to the way that unknown XML tags can be safely skipped;

Example: 
Imagine a message to make a telephone call. In a first version of a system this might use two message elements, a "command" and a "phoneNumberToCall":

command_c/4/makeCall_c/phoneNumberToCall_c/8/"722-4246"
Here command_c, makeCall_c and phoneNumberToCall_c are integer constants and 4 and 8 are the lengths of the "value" fields, respectively.

Later (in version 2) a new field containing the calling number could be added:
command_c/4/makeCall_c/callingNumber_c/8/"715-9719"/phoneNumberToCall_c/8/"722-4246"

A version 1 system which received a message from a version 2 system would first read the command_c element and then read an element of type callingNumber_c.

The version 1 system does not understand ;callingNumber_c
so the length field is read (i.e. the first 8) and the system skips forward 8 bytes to read
phoneNumberToCall_c which it understands, and message parsing carries on.

Without the type field, the version 1 parser would not know to skip callingNumber_c and instead call the wrong number and maybe throw an error on the rest of the message. So the type field allows for forward compatibility in a way that omiting it does not.

Comment: I considered this as well, but it can just as easily be done using only the length. If the command is not understood, you only need the length to skip it.